# my MCU 8051 IDE got error while launching

Tags: ide, 8051

Upon launching, my window pop up a console said:
"
THE IDE WAS ORIGINALY WRITTEN FOR POSIX, SO IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOME
FUNCTIONALITY WILL BE LIMITED ON MS WINDOWS DUE TO ABSENCE OF CERTAIN
POSIX FUNCTIONALITY!
Error sourcing /home/millenium/mcu8051ide/pkgs/installation_sandbox/lib/main.tcl: can't read "value": no such variable
() 1 %
"
I tried reinstall it but still not fixing the problem

How to solve this problem?

Comment: *"How to solve this problem?"* -- Try running the IDE on a POSIX compliant platform.  Linux definitely, WLS ... maybe, MacOS ... maybe.  (Hint: you can always but another machine to do your 8051 dev work.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- Please [edit] your question and add which IDE in what version you try to run. I suggest to add URLs to its manufacturer and the documentation, too. -- Was this the first start at all after the first installation?